# Responsive scrolltop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop

Im using the following code to detect when an object should become 'sticky' and stay fixed in its content.

```
var $window = $(window),
    $stickyEl = $('#single-post-details'),
    elTop = $stickyEl.offset().top;

$window.scroll(function() {
    $stickyEl.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() + 52 > elTop);
});
```

However I would like to make this responsive. This means that somehow it needs to detect the height of the banner above it first so that it doesn't trigger at the wrong point.. [Here is a fiddle with as an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/en62c3kq/1/)

Comment: Responsive is so hard to do using scripting. Why do you not use CSS?

Comment: You mean like this : http://jsfiddle.net/en62c3kq/2/?

Comment: thats not responsive though, if you scale it and scroll the text is going ontop of the image

Comment: @PeterRader how would you recommend doing a sticky div without jquery and just css? As I would prefer not to use jquery

Comment: Did it in 1 minute, didn't check all the possibility, but is that what you was asking? (fixed version here : http://jsfiddle.net/en62c3kq/4/)

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon yes that is exactly it thank you very much. Do you want to put at in the answer.  If not I can :)

Comment: You're welcome. I'll make an answer with the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that on the resize, the top position of you sticky element change. To solve that, you should not check the height of the image, but recalculate the top position.

The use of `.resize` event is usefull here. On the callback, just update you global variable :

```
var $window = $(window),
    $stickyEl = $('#single-post-details'),
    elTop = $stickyEl.offset().top;

$window.on({
    resize : function(){
        elTop = $stickyEl.offset().top;
        $window.trigger('scroll');
    },
    scroll : function() {
        $stickyEl.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() + 20 > elTop);
    }
});
```

**Note:** the `trigger('scroll')` is important to prevent the sticky element to go over the image while expanding the window.

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/en62c3kq/4/)