# $anyid.offset().top; change the behavior of my website

Tags: jquery

Coming from [Responsive scrolltop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975011/responsive-scrolltop/25975409#25975409)

I am using wordpress when i load this code my website change its behaviour. for example, i cant click on submenu (with hover disappear) and sliders don't load even after changing the variables, but when i comment `var elTop = $stickyBar.offset().top;` it loads normally.
I don't know what nor where the problem is.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var $window = $(window);
var $stickyBar = $('#pg-9-2');
var elTop = $stickyBar.offset().top;

$window.on({
    resize : function(){
        elTop = $stickyBar.offset().top;
        $window.trigger('scroll');
    },
    scroll : function() {
        $stickyBar.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() + 0 > elTop);
    }
});
```

});